# Converting a list of strings into an array of strings

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I have a list of strings where each string is essentially a line of data pulled in from a .csv program.
For example:

```
data[0] = '2014-01-31,46.83,48.55,46.80,48.03,3414400,48.03'

data[1] = '2014-01-30,47.47,48.11,47.29,48.00,2083900,48.00'
```

...etc.

I want to convert this into a a two-dimensional list such that:

```
newData[0][0] = '2014-01-31'
newData[0][0] = '2014-01-30'
newData[1][0] = '46.83'
newData[1][1] = '47.47'
```

...etc

That is, I want to split the strings at each `,` but when I tried using `data.split(",")` it doesn't want to do it because it's a list.  Any ideas?

Comment: please fix your formatting

Comment: Use a `csv.reader` so your data never gets into that format.

Answer (score 4):

Apply `str.split` on the items of the list:

```
newData = [item.split(',') for item in data]
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> data = ['2014-01-31,46.83,48.55,46.80,48.03,3414400,48.03', '2014-01-30,47.47,48.11,47.29,48.00,2083900,48.00']
>>> newData = [item.split(',') for item in data] 
>>> newData[0][0]
'2014-01-31'
>>> newData[1][0]
'2014-01-30'
```

As others have pointed out you should use `csv` module to read the data from a csv file, considering that the file contains:

```
2014-01-31,46.83,48.55,46.80,48.03,3414400,48.03
2014-01-30,47.47,48.11,47.29,48.00,2083900,48.00
```

This code will give the desired output:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)
```